# How to detect scroll event on a ListView?

Tags: javascript, titanium

Does anyone know of a way to detect a vertical scroll/swipe gesture on a ListView? I tried listening to swipe event but it only fires on left-to-right and right-to-left gestures, not up or down. I also tried listening on the parent View which resulted in the same behavior.
Thanks in advance for any tips or tricks! :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like this is supported, but one way is to set the list views height to Ti.UI.SIZE so that it does not scroll, and then put it inside a ScrollView. Then listen for the [`scroll`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-event-scroll) event on the ScrollView. Try something like this:

```
// Vertical scroll view
var parentScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height : 'auto'
});

// Make a list view that does not scroll
var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
   height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
   ... Other initialization here ...
});

parentScrollView.add(listView);
parentScrollView.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    // This lets you know where you scrolled to
    var scrollX = e.x;
    var scrollY = e.y;

    // Alternatively use contentOffset
    var contentOffsetScoped = e.source.contentOffset;
    var contentOffsetSame = parentScrollView.contentOffset;
});
```

This is a minimalist example, but works. Note that this approach may take away any performance gains from the ListView control so it might be better to just convert to using a TableView.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix for the issue in the nightly builds, but currently this is an open issue

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14317